# Question about the matrix operation

Tags: matrix

I was wondering if there is an automatic way to do this kind of matrix operation.

For example, for a given matrix

```
list = {{1, 3T}, {3, 8T}, {2, 2T}, {1, 5T}, {4, 6T}};
```

I want the result to be like this as shown below after the operation.

```
result = {{1 ,8T}, {2, 2T}, {3, 8T}, {4, 6T}}
```

The operation will add the terms in the second column if they have the same number in the first column for all the rows. i.e. for the first row, the second term is calculated as `3T` plus `5T`,which is the term in `list[[4,2]]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Oska. Much appreciated!

Comment: `{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[list, First] // Sort`?

Comment: Just another way: `SortBy[Last@Reap[Sow @@@ (Reverse /@ list), _, {#1, Total@#2} &], First]`...omit `SortBy` if order not important

Comment: Nice to see so many contributions, and thanks for the heads up!